# How to make mat-select of Angular Material do the line break, in a mobile application?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-material

I already have the mat-select built with Angular Material, but when the big text I would like to go to the next line, so that it shows the full text.

This is the HTML code:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="element.control">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of elements" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This is how it looks in the application:

[image]

Making the changes recommended by ビ ー ト フ リ ー ク ス:

try add this on global.scss :

```
.mat-select-value {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.width-mat {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: 3em;
    height: unset;
}

.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    font-size  : inherit;
    line-height: 2em;
    height     : unset;
    white-space: unset;
    border-bottom: var(--Gray1) solid 1px;
}
```

on your html add the panelClass :

```
<mat-select 
    panelClass="width-mat" 
    disableOptionCentering
    disableRipple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of elements" value={{option}}>
              {{option}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add this on global.scss :

```
.mat-select-value {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.width-mat {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: 2em;
    height: unset;
}

.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    font-size  : inherit;
    line-height: 1em;
    height     : unset;
    white-space: unset;
}
```

on your html add the panelClass :

```
<mat-select 
    panelClass="width-mat" 
    disableOptionCentering
    disableRipple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of elements" value={{option}}>
              {{option}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

u can try my sample here : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjhn5e?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: @sergioandresmorenoherrera try adjusting the line-height to 1em

Comment: I add some sample code on stackblizt u can try it there